# How convert strings in format 43004 to date in python dataframe?

Tags: python, datetime, lambda, format, apply

I need convert strings in dataframe to date. But sometimes is empty cells and rest of them is in format like 43004. (Data are from excel)

I tried this

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
OutputDataSet1['Previous_Received_Date'] = OutputDataSet1['Previous_Received_Date'].apply(lambda x:  datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30) + datetime.timedelta(days=  datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30) + datetime.timedelta(days= OutputDataSet1['Previous_Received_Date']) if not pd.isnull(x) else np.nan)
```

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

the row in dataframe looks like this

```
nan
nan
43125.00000
nan
nan
43129,00000
nan
```

There are more like 5000 rows and I don't know how many are nan and how many are number.

Other options is change the format directly in excel, but I have to do it using python. I don't know how do it nether.